# Confused by a part of a code

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, foreach

There is a part of a code for "making the first letter of each word capitalized" I dont understand.
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/117463/

```
std::string str = x;
str [0] = toupper (str[0]);
std::for_each(str.begin()+1, str.end(), printChars);
std::cout << str;
return 0;
}

Void printChars(char& c)
{
   if( (*(&c - sizeof(char))) == " ")
       c = toupper(c);
}
```

I understand it sets the first letter to capital always, and checks for each one in the string after.

But why does he use `if((*(&c - sizeof(char))) == " ")` and how does the *** , *&* and setting it to blank work in this case?

Comment: This program is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: I guess that this code _tries_ to detect if the previous character was a space, and if so - make the current character capitalized. However, even if, the example you show, does not _seem_ to exhibit UB (undefined behavior), you should be careful with the usage of such function, since calling it on a first element of an array (or just a single character), would, in fact, exhibit UB. EDIT: I just noticed that the comparison being done is `== " "`, which would barely ever be equal (and would, probably result in compiler warning), since you are comparing `char` with `char*`.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: The code is ill-formed, which means that it is non-compilable (and traditional C++ compilers are not known for issuing a mere "warning" for such an error). The OP apparently failed to propely reproduce the origial code (which is also evident from the `Void`). There's no way the real code would have that `" "` there.

Comment: You should avoid making your own "simplifications" when you don't understand the code you are working on... comparing your code with the original from the link, you have introduced several errors

Comment: @AnT Well, I noticed that he was trying to compare against a string, and not against a character, after I wrote my initial comment. And, without trying to compile, didn't know if such comparison would throw a warning, or an error. After trying to compile it, I noticed that it is, indeed, an error. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

> how does ... work in this case?

It does not work. The program that you show is ill-formed and is not likely to compile.

> ```
> Void printChars(char& c)
> ```

There is no type `Void` in C++. I suspect that you intended to write `void` instead.

> ```
> (some_char_value) == " " // expression simplified by me
> ```

You may not compare a character to a string literal.

---

> But why does he use `if((*(&c - sizeof(char))) == " ")`

He doesn't. He uses `if( (*(&c - sizeof(char))) == ' ')`.

> how does the & work in this case?

It is the address-of operator. It is used here to get a temporary pointer to the memory address of `c`.

> how does the * work in this case?

It is the indirection operator. It is used here to get the character at the memory location `&c - 1`. Which is a character in `str` right before the character referred to by `c`.

> and setting it to blank work in this case?

He doesn't set anything in the quoted expression. `==` is the equality comparison operator. He compares the values of the `&c - 1` and the character literal `' '`.

In english: He tests whether the character before `c` is space. In other words: He test whether `c` is the first character of a word.

Comment: `- 1` should be used instead of `- sizeof(char)` ... they are equivalent because the standard defines `sizeof(char) == 1` but the latter is confusing and hurts readability

Answer (score 0):

This code is performing simple pointer arithmetic. The code you are asking about is using the reference operator `&` to grab the address of the variable `c`. Then performing subtraction of the size of a char to check if the char before c is a space if so it calls `toUpper()`. So for example

if the address of c is 100 then `&c - sizeof(char)` is checking the char at address 99 then the * is used to dereference the variable which allows for the comparison of the variable using `== " "`.